# Jenkins Cannot run program "Xvfb": java.io.IOException :no such file or directory

Tags: grails, jenkins, spock, geb, xvfb

I'm trying to run grails geb/spock tests on jenkins. I install Xvfb Plugin 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin. 
Jenkins configurations:
[image]

Project configuration:
[image]

Exception:
[image]

Comment: You may not have xvfb installed. Try installing it: http://serverfault.com/questions/344793/install-xvfb-via-yum-yum-repository-for-xvfb

Comment: But in jenkins in instaled plugins I have it with the version 1.0.16.

Comment: have you checked the docs about the installation?  is xvfb just not accessible/runable for the user jenkins runs as?

Comment: plugin probably _assumes_  xvfb is present. You need to install it  as admin. I see that plugin installation has option to install xvfb.  Did you try checking that option (Install Automatically)?

Comment: Tried to run with Install Automatically option but the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you install the Xvfb Plugin, you have to do: Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and find the Xvfb Installation section and add an installation with a Name and Directory in which to find Xvfb executable (which can be blank if it can be found in the PATH).  Without this setting, Xvfb doesn't work.

So, why not search the PATH by default?  Why should this be needed??